# JSON API format in API-Platform

Tags: symfony, json-api, api-platform.com

First of all I want to implement [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/). 
I follow [tutorial on api platform](https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution#bringing-your-own-model) and just like in example create entities and response is like

```
{
    "links": {
        "self": "/api/books"
    },
    "meta": {
        "totalItems": 1,
        "itemsPerPage": 30,
        "currentPage": 1
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "/api/books/1",
            "type": "Book",
            "attributes": {
                "isbn": "9781782164104",
                "title": "Persistence in PHP with the Doctrine ORM",
                "description": "This book is designed for PHP developers and architects who want to modernize their skills through better understanding of Persistence and ORM.",
                "author": "Kévin Dunglas",
                "publicationDate": "2013-12-01T00:00:00+01:00",
                "_id": 1
            },
            "relationships": {
                "reviews": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "type": "Review",
                            "id": "/api/reviews/1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My `api_platform.yaml` config

```
api_platform:
    mapping:
        paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']
    formats:
        jsonapi:
            mime_types: ['application/vnd.api+json']
```

So i have problem with `id` filed in `data`. I get `id` fields in format `api/entityName/id` but I just want to get  number(string), just like [in JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/). So is there some configuration that i miss or is any way to achieve that

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to send

```
Accept: application/json
```

on request header.

Answer (score 0):

It was discussed [here](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/249).
You need to use Normalizer or create custom getter.

Comment: Can you give me some example or some tutorial. Documentation on official site is not very good, especially when is JSON API format. If you are familiar with API-Platform can you look [API platform filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965324/api-platform-filter-entity-data)

Comment: You can create a custom controller for GET action like  [described in the documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers), then create a custom request to the database and return JSON the response wit id's you want.