# API Platform filter entity data

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I just start to use [Api platform](https://api-platform.com/) and immediately stuck with problem how to filter data.
I have entity `User` and i want to filter data that are present in response ( JSON API format)

```
{
    "links": {
        "self": "/api/users"
    },
    "meta": {
        "totalItems": 2,
        "itemsPerPage": 30,
        "currentPage": 1
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "/api/users/1",
            "type": "User",
            "attributes": {
                "_id": 1,
                "username": "jonhdoe",
                "isActive": true,
                "address": null
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "/api/users/3",
            "type": "User",
            "attributes": {
                "_id": 3,
                "username": "test",
                "isActive": true,
                "address": null
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

so I want to remove e.g. `User` with `id` 3, but not use filters sent via request. I just want to set filter that will be always run when someone go to `/api/users`. 
I look to [api-platform extensions](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/) but this will be applied on each request e.g. `/api/trucks`. So at end I just want to get something like

```
{
    "links": {
        "self": "/api/users"
    },
    "meta": {
        "totalItems": 1,
        "itemsPerPage": 30,
        "currentPage": 1
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "/api/users/1",
            "type": "User",
            "attributes": {
                "_id": 1,
                "username": "jonhdoe",
                "isActive": true,
                "address": null
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations

Answer (score 3):

As you pointed out, [extensions](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/) are the way to go.

The `applyToCollection` method gets a `$resourceClass` parameter containing the current resource class.

So you can apply the `WHERE` clause only for a specific class in this method like:

```
public function applyToCollection(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null)
{
    if (User::class === $resourceClass) {
        $queryBuilder->doSomething();
    }
    // Do nothing for other classes
}
```